# Spring JPA - deleting child element doesn't reflect in database table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having problems deleting the child element of a one-to-many relationship entity.
Here's a code snippet:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteTask(UUID listId, UUID taskId) {
    TaskList list = repo.findOne(listId);

    System.out.println("Old List: " + list);

    for(Task t : list.getTasks()) {
        if(t.getId().toString().equals(taskId.toString())) {
            System.out.println(list.getTasks().remove(t));
            System.out.println("Task with id " + taskId + " deleted.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("New List: " + repo.save(list));
}
```

The Task class is this:

```
@Entity(name = "task")
public class Task implements Serializable {    

    // Id and 3 fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tasklist_id")
    private TaskList parentList;

    // 3 more fields

    // Constructor
    public Task() {}

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

and the TaskList class is this:

```
@Entity(name = "task_list")
public class TaskList implements Serializable {

    // Id and two fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentList", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Task> tasks;

    // Constructor
    public TaskList() {}
}
```

The `Task` entity is the child, and even though the save() function returns the truncated `TaskList`, I can't get the changes to show in a separate query to the database. The number of tasks remains the same. However, deleting a list through `repo.delete(listId)` works fine with both the list and its tasks gone.

Here, `repo` is a repository corresponding to the parent `TaskList` class. All operations to the child `Task` class happen through a `@OneToMany({cascade=CascadeType.ALL})` relation.

For some reason, searching for all `TaskList`s using `repo.findAll()` also returns faulty results.

I'm obviously doing something fundamentally wrong. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: I've also tried `saveAndFlush()` without success.

Comment: @ArunM Added entities.

Comment: Update: Using a `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` for the relation seems to solve the problem of `findAll()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `orphanRemoval = true` to your mapping:

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentList", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)`

`list.getTasks().remove(t)` just removes entity from the collection, so you need to tell JPA to remove it also from DB. This is done by the `orphanRemoval` attribute.

Comment: @cst1992 I've extended by answer

Comment: It works. Thanks. Could you explain why `findAll()` could be faulty? I have two lists with two tasks each, but it prints one list once, and the second one thrice instead of once.

Comment: It's hard do say from just this code snippet. Generally you don't need to call `repo.save`, as this is tracked by JPA. Returning doubled results looks like a lack of distinct but it shouldn't affect simple findAll query. Also remember to accept answer while it's correct :)

Comment: Hi, it seems it's in a function unrelated to this. Thanks, you helped a lot! :)

Comment: Hi again. I managed to circumvent the problem of the `findAll()` using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations. The excess printing was due to some rogue setter which I never managed to fix. These annotations allow me to use the object references directly. Doing so was otherwise leading to StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my task list

```
@Entity(name = "TASK_LIST")
public class TaskList {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "task", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

Here's my repository

```
@Repository
public interface TaskListRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskList, Long> {
}
```

Here's my test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext-test.xml")
public class TaskListRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TaskListRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService service;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws SQLException {

        TaskList taskList = new TaskList();
        taskList.getTasks().add(makeTask("name1", "description1"));
        taskList.getTasks().add(makeTask("name2", "description2"));
        taskList.getTasks().add(makeTask("name3", "description3"));
        taskList.getTasks().add(makeTask("name4", "description4"));
        taskList.getTasks().add(makeTask("name5", "description5"));

        service.save(taskList);

        TaskList findOne = repository.findOne(1l);
        assertEquals(5, findOne.getTasks().size());

        taskList.getTasks().remove(2);
        service.save(taskList);

        findOne = repository.findOne(1l);
        assertEquals(4, findOne.getTasks().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws SQLException {

        TaskList findOne = repository.findOne(1l);
        assertEquals(4, findOne.getTasks().size());
    }

    private Task makeTask(String name, String description) {

        Task task = new Task();
        task.setName(name);
        task.setDescription(description);
        return task;
    }
```

Comment: Pretty similar to my code, as close as it gets. I suggest you remove all but the last snippet; they don't add anything useful. Edit: I have removed them.

Comment: Using `indexOf()`, I'm getting an index of 0, but it won't delete if I pass that index to `remove()`. Actually it will, but it isn't reflecting in the database.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: I had to change to add the orphanRemoval=true and added a service to wrap the repo to get the transaction to take effect, a bit confused.